# Is the set Closed, Open or neither?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following set, closed, open, or neither?

$$
\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x \geq 0, y \geq 0 \text { and } x y>1\right\}
$$

I looked at the complement and (possibly incorrectly) deduced that it was neither closed nor open. I believe this means that the set itself cannot be closed or open either.

Comment: What made you think that the complement was not closed?

Comment: It's usually easier to decide whether a set is open than whether it is closed. So I would suggest checking whether the set itself is open, and whether the complement is open, and forget about closed. At least as a first approach.

Comment: @user3482749 My mistake, chose a wrong sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open set. Note that your set is equal to$$\bigl\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x+y>0\text{ and }xy>1\bigr\}.$$Therefore, it is equal to $F^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\times(1,\infty)\bigr)$, with $F(x,y)=(x+y,xy)$. Besides, $F$ is continuous.